# How can i keep two values in c++

Tags: c++, c++14

I have few pairs of elements : `(3 1),(2 0),(3 0),(1 2),(4 1),(0 4),(0 1)`
How or where can i keep them? In multidimensional array?
I thought about array but not sure

Comment: since you have pairs of elements why not `std::pair`

Comment: Lookup `std::pair` or provide your own `struct`.

Comment: Structures? [Pairs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)? [Tuples](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)? In a [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: One option of many follows.   Each pair in a `std::pair`  (e.g. an `std::pair<int, double>` assuming the paired values are of type `int` and `double`).   A `std::vector<std::pair<int, double> >` for a collection of such pairs.

Comment: What is the context of this; why do you want to keep pairs of values? Have you looked up potential solutions (I find http://cppreference.com to be a good resource), and if so why do you think they might not work for you?

Comment: Also, everybody is suggesting `std::pair`, which would (probably, depending on use case) work. However, if the numbers have specific meanings (points in a plane, for example), you can make your own `struct` to give the variables better names (eg. `struct point {int x; int y;};` will let you say `p.x` instead of `p.first`, which would be more readable if they were points).

Answer (score 3):

If you have pairs you can use `std:pair`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pairs = {{3, 1},{2, 0}};
```

If you know in advance how many pairs you will have then you can use `std::array`:

```
std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 2> pairs = {{{3, 1},{2, 0}}};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep them in, more or less, any container you want. A `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` would seem the most natural to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//Typedef the nasty name to a readable name
typedef std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > Container;

int main()
{
    //Make a variable of our container
    Container ctr;

    //Now make pairs and push them to the container
    ctr.push_back(std::make_pair(3,1));
    ctr.push_back(std::make_pair(2,0));
    ctr.push_back(std::make_pair(3,0));
    ctr.push_back(std::make_pair(1,2));
    ctr.push_back(std::make_pair(4,1));

    //If you don't believe the above code, print the container :)
    for(auto it = ctr.begin(); it < ctr.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << it->first << ":" << it->second << std::endl;   
    return 0;
}
```